# Ajax event for Calendar not working when cleared the selection in primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, calendar

I am trying to use **DateSelect** event for **calendar** as follows.I am able to get  the values properly and the event also gets triggered. However when I clear the date ,it doesn't take the *null* value,it keeps the previous value.
How do I capture *DateSelect* and clear selection, both at the same time.

```
<p:calendar widgetVar="fTransStartDate" id="fTransStartDate" title="Enter the Trans Start Date" readonlyInput="false" value="#{TransactionViewer.trns_ts_start}" size="25" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" navigator="true" yearRange="c-100:c+100" disabled="true">
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{TransactionViewer.disable}"/> </p:calendar>
```

Comment: why you have disabled="true" in p:calendar ?

Comment: because i keep it disabled when page loads first time..Later i make it true.